# Classification based on different columns of a dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, classification

I have a dataframe with different columns:

```
ID     Age    Marital_statut

1      10     1
1      50     2 
1      52     2
2      32     2
2      38     2
3      13     3                
3      34     3               
4      10     1                
4      50     2                
4      52     2                
4      11     1
```

Expected output:

```
ID     Age    Marital_statut   Family Statut

1      10     1                2 with children under 12
1      50     2                2 with children under 12
1      52     2                2 with children under 12 
2      32     2                2 without children
2      38     2                2 without children
3      13     1                3 with children above 12
3      34     3                3 with children above 12
4      10     1                2 with two children under 12
4      50     2                2 with two children under 12
4      52     2                2 with two children under 12 
4      11     1                2 with two children under 12
```

How to get the Family Statut? 
The algorithm will count how many person with the same Marital_Statut 1, 2 and 3 and the same ID, thus for each ID we will get the number of people with Marital_Statut 1 (single), 2 (married) and 3 (divorced) . 
Then, If for a given ID the count of Marital Statut 2 = 2 , Marital Statut 1 = 0 and Marital Statut 3 = 0 then its  Family Statut= 2 without children.
Another example If for a given ID the count of Marital Statut 2 = 2, Marital Statut 3 = 0 and  Marital Statut 1 = 1 then the algorithm will check the column Age of the Marital Statut 1 and if the Age<12 then  Family Statut= 2 with children under 12

I was thinking about groupby for counting Marital Statut but after that I don't know how to do it.
`df.groupby(["ID","Marital_statut"])["Marital_statut"].count().unstack()`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you're getting the Family Statut column?

Comment: I've added new examples. I hope it will help :)

Comment: Your example is really a simplified version. There are a lot of possibilities than what you listed above. For example, what if there are 2 children, one above 12 and one under 12? What will that be?

Comment: Yes you're right. I did a simplified version and then I will add a condition if it is the case @TYZ

Comment: ID=3, there is a child above 12.  Yes this is why I ask how can we do it?

Comment: `3      13     3                3 with children above 12` How come you have a 13-year-old that's divorced?? Shouldn't `Marital_statut` be 1?